# Search text file for value and return everything after it

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable `$name = 'my.name';`

I have a text file called `people.txt` which contains the following:

```
my.name@mysite.com|
my.friend@othersite.com|
my.enemy@anothersite.com|
```

I'd like to be able to use the variable to basically search the contents of the text file and return the value `mysite.com`. So basically, whatever follows `my.name` before the pipe.

---

Here's my script so far:

```
$file = "people.txt";
$searchfor = 'my.name';

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
$search_for = 'my.name';

$pattern = sprintf('/\b%s@([^|\s]+)\|/m', preg_quote($search_for));

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[1]);
} else {
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

The output for your current input fragment:

```
Found matches:
mysite.com
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. Would $contents be `people.txt`?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk, it's your actual `$contents = file_get_contents($file);`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a literal `$` with the `\$` remove the backslash and you should be good.

An alternative pattern with the same result could be:

```
\b$pattern[\s\S]*
```

Comment: Many thanks @user3783243 - will give this a try right now.

Comment: Oh, I might have misread, do you want everything after the match, or just the match until the `|`? From the title I read it as everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern@([^|]+\)|/m";
```

`[^|]+` means any character, at least once (`+`), but NOT `|`

`\|` escapes `|` as it's meaningful in this context

`()` is a capturing group, which lets you to later reference captured values in `$matches`. Since you use `preg_match_all`, all the matches for the first captured group (and the only one) will be available at `$matches[1]`.

Comment: You said you want to match until `|`.

Comment: Wasn't my question but I guess depends. Question varies `return everything after it` or `before the pipe`.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk so now you removed your comment and basically accepted a very similar answer.